# error: 'SO_STATE' undeclared

Tags: c, sockets, solaris-10

There is a macro "SO_STATE" in socket.h , which not seems to present in solaris 10.

consider following program:

```
 #include <stdio.h>  
 #include <unistd.h>  
 #include <stdlib.h>  
 #include <errno.h>  
 #include <string.h>  
 #include <sys/types.h>  
 #include <sys/socket.h>  
 #include <assert.h>  

/* 
 * This function reports the error and 
 * exits back to the shell: 
 */  
 static void  
 displayError(const char *on_what) {  
  if ( errno != 0 ) {  
      fputs(strerror(errno),stderr);  
      fputs(": ",stderr);  
  }  
  fputs(on_what,stderr);  
  fputc('\n',stderr);  
  exit(1);  
 }  

 int main(int argc,char **argv) {  
  int z;  
  int s = -1;       /* Socket */  
  int sndbuf=0;     /* Send buffer size */  
  int rcvbuf=0;     /* Receive buffer size */  
  socklen_t optlen; /* Option length */  

    /* 
  * Create a TDP/IP socket to use: 
  */  
  s = socket(PF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);  
  if ( s == -1 ) {  
    displayError("socket(2)");  
  }  

 /* 
  * Get socket option SO_SNDBUF: 
  */  
  optlen = sizeof sndbuf;  
  z = getsockopt(s,  
                 SOL_SOCKET,  
                 SO_STATE,  
                 &sndbuf,&optlen);  
  if ( z ) {  
    displayError("getsockopt(s,SOL_SOCKET,"   
                     "SO_SNDBUF)");  
  }  

  assert(optlen == sizeof sndbuf);  

 /* 
  * Get socket option SO_SNDBUF: 
  */  
  optlen = sizeof rcvbuf;  
  z = getsockopt(s,  
                 SOL_SOCKET,  
                 SO_RCVBUF,  
                 &rcvbuf,&optlen);  
  if ( z ) {  
    displayError("getsockopt(s,SOL_SOCKET,"  
                 "SO_RCVBUF)");  
  }  

  assert(optlen == sizeof rcvbuf);  

 /* 
  * Report the buffer sizes: 
  */  
  printf( "Socket s : %d\n",s);  
  printf( "Send buf: %d bytes\n", sndbuf);  
  printf( "Recv buf: %d bytes\n", rcvbuf);  

  close(s);  
  return 0;  
 }
```

when I compile it in solaris 10 , I get following error:

> sock.c: In function 'main': sock.c:47: error: 'SO_STATE' undeclared
>   (first use in this function) sock.c:47: error: (Each undeclared
>   identifier is reported only once sock.c:47: error: for each function
>   it appears in.)

when I compile it in solaris 8 , Its compiling successfully.

what is different in solaris 10?

SO_STATE is present in socket.h in solaris 8 then why it is removed in solaris 10? following is from solaris 8.

```
cat /usr/include/sys/socket.h |grep SO_STATE
#define SO_STATE        0x2000          /* Internal: get so_state */
```

while SO_STATE is not present in socket.h in solaris 10.

Comment: On my Ubuntu 15.04i get the same error. i don't see this macro http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html

Comment: "what is different in solaris 10?" Apparently the non-existence of this option (among many other things too much to tell here). What was your question?

Comment: I see that SO_STATE is present in **socketvar.h**

Comment: @olaf: I just want to know that why this option is not available in solaris 10?